# How do I access other elements in my predefined structured object in C#/Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a predefined object called FOOD. Inside is a GameObject that points to a PreFab GameObject. That GameObject is also attached to a collision script. My question is, how do I access other elements of my structure such as health, calories, etc, inside my collision script?

```
public class FOODS: ScriptableObject
{
public GameObject preFabFood; 
//points to a prefab object that is attached to a collision script

int health;
int calories;
float height;
float width;
}

//this is the script that is attached to the GameObject preFabFood
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
{
    //how do I access elements such as height, weight, etc?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## You have two problems.

1) The properties are `private`, meaning that they aren't visible to other classes. The default visibility on member fields [is private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#class-and-struct-member-accessibility).

2) The properties aren't in a script attached to your prefab.

Fixing #2 (as Soraphis) suggests is *sort of* the right thing to do, however, you would want to remove the `public GameObject preFabFood;` field from your `FOODS` class if you're attaching the `FOODS` class to the prefab instance (as you don't need to carry a copy of the instantiated object *with* the instantiation). Just keep this in mind as you adjust your code (the code you posted looks like one script, but I suspect its supposed to be more than one, and should in fact be at least 2).

As for fixing #1, you have to make them public *or* access them from the same script. If you directly attach your `FOODS` class to your instantiated prefab and that the `FOODS` class contains the `OnCollisionEnter2D` method, then everything's fine.

But as I suspect you've got *two* classes that you're showing here, you'll need to do this:

```
public int health;
public int calories;
public float height;
public float width;
```

And then use a `GetComponent()` call from to get the one script from the other. e.g.

```
FOODS foods = this.gameObject.GetComponent<FOODS>(); //gets the FOODS script attached to this game object.
//Functionally identical to GetComponent<FOODS>();
int hp = foods.health; //etc
```

Note that you should call `GetComponent` as little as possible, because it has a non-zero overhead, so caching the result as soon as possible (e.g. you could do it in `Start()` instead of every time at the top of `OnCollisionEnter2D`), but this is more of a general "be careful" flag, as over-use can cause frame rate issues.

Comment: @user9512695 As a side note, the standard naming conventions for classes is PascalCase, that is, `Foods` not `FOODS`. You're free to do whatever you like, but it makes your code easier for other people to understand (as well as more descriptive naming, such as `FoodStats` or `FoodProperties`).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I access other elements of my structure such as health, calories, etc, inside my collision script?

you can't. but you can solve it like this:

in your CollisionScript, change the `GameObject PrefabFood` to your scriptable object `FOODS food`

then in this class you can access things like so:

```
food.preFabFood // is the prefab
food.health // is the health variable
```

---

it seams like you're quite new to coding and i'd suggest learning the basics before, because this is basic programming and isn't really unity or even c# related.